# How to get popular tweets in twitter api

Tags: javascript, twitter, nestjs

I am writing a project on Nestjs and ran into a problem. Here is the question, I need to get the most popular tweets by keyword from the twitter api, but in api version 2 I can't find how to request popular tweets. In version 1.1 there is a parameter result_type = popular, but in version 2 there is nothing like that, I can only get the latest tweets. Who knows how to get popular tweets, tell me how to do it.

```
async fetchTopTweetsData(keyword: string) {
    const cacheValue = await this.cache.get(`${keyword}`)
    if (cacheValue) {
      return this.cache.get(`${keyword}`)
    }
    AppLogger.log('Twitter module has been updated')
    const accessToken = await this.cache.get('bearerToken')
    const twitterClient = new TwitterApi(accessToken.access_token)

    const response = await twitterClient.v2.get('tweets/search/recent', {
      query: `#${keyword}`,
      max_results: 20,
    })
    await this.cache.set(`${keyword}`, 115)
    return this.cache.get(`${keyword}`)
  }
```

Comment: Since there is no API parameter in v2, you will need to build something yourself that filters by e.g. likes and retweets after you have retrieved the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very poor update for version 2. You write the logic for separating tweets with a high rating yourself. But why was it necessary to remove this function? This question was resolved by the fact that I applied the request method from version 1 [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=${keyword}&result_type=popular](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=$%7Bkeyword%7D&result_type=popular).

Comment: Feel free to provide requests for updates to the API via the feedback channel https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com/